# Relationships not created in PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize.js as ORM in node.js, I need to build some relationships.

I have no great experience in SQL RDMSs, possibly I'm missing some point here.

I have 4 different models. All of them should have cross-relationship with each other.

```
//  consider there are catch blocks calling 'console.error(err)', consequently each then
Q.all([Building, Lesson, Section, Course, Schedule]
    .reduce(function(array, element) {
        return element.sync();
    }, [])
) .then(function () {
    return Section.hasMany(Lesson);
}).then(function () {
    return Lesson.belongsTo(Section);
}).then(function () {
    return Course.hasMany(Section);
}).then(function () {
    return Section.belongsTo(Course);
}).then(function () {
    return Schedule.hasMany(Course);
}).then(function () {
    return Course.belongsTo(Schedule);
}).then(function () {
    return Q.all([Building, Lesson, Section, Course, Schedule]
        .reduce(function(array, element) {
            return element.sync();
        }, [])
    )
});
```

There is no error thrown in catch blocks of any Promise I invoked, also no unhandled rejections. However when I try to create new objects, I'm not able to do that, throwing this error:

```
{ [SequelizeDatabaseError: column "scheduleId" does not exist]
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  message: 'column "scheduleId" does not exist',
  parent: 
   { [error: column "scheduleId" does not exist]
     name: 'error',
     length: 104,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42703',
     detail: undefined,
     hint: undefined,
     position: '117',
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: undefined,
     table: undefined,
     column: undefined,
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: undefined,
     file: 'parse_relation.c',
     line: '2892',
     routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
     sql: 'SELECT "id", "code", "number", "isEnglish", "title", "prerequisites", "classRestriction", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "scheduleId" FROM "course" AS "course" WHERE "course"."code" = \'BEN\' AND "course"."number" = \'102\' AND "course"."isEnglish" = false AND "course"."title" = \'Microbiology\' LIMIT 1;' },
  original: 
   { [error: column "scheduleId" does not exist]
     name: 'error',
     length: 104,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42703',
     detail: undefined,
     hint: undefined,
     position: '117',
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: undefined,
     table: undefined,
     column: undefined,
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: undefined,
     file: 'parse_relation.c',
     line: '2892',
     routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
     sql: 'SELECT "id", "code", "number", "isEnglish", "title", "prerequisites", "classRestriction", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "scheduleId" FROM "course" AS "course" WHERE "course"."code" = \'BEN\' AND "course"."number" = \'102\' AND "course"."isEnglish" = false AND "course"."title" = \'Microbiology\' LIMIT 1;' },
  sql: 'SELECT "id", "code", "number", "isEnglish", "title", "prerequisites", "classRestriction", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "scheduleId" FROM "course" AS "course" WHERE "course"."code" = \'BEN\' AND "course"."number" = \'102\' AND "course"."isEnglish" = false AND "course"."title" = \'Microbiology\' LIMIT 1;'
}
```

One more thing, I'm also inspecting the SQL with pgAdmin, there is no such as `ScheduleId` or any relationship-related column in my models. Should I add them manually in model declarations?

[image: pgAdmin]

Here are the model definitions:

```
pool = new Sequelize("postgres://Instigater@localhost:5432/Instigater");

Building = pool.define("building", {
    shortName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    longName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    campus: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,    //    will be changed to enum
    },
    image: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
}, {
    freezeTableName: true // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
});

Lesson = pool.define("lesson", {
    room: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    weekday: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,    //    will be changed to enum
    },
    startTime: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    endTime: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
}, {
    freezeTableName: true // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
});

Section = pool.define("section", {
    //    CRN is the identifier of a section
    crn: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    //    Instructor of the section
    instructor: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    capacity: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    enrolled: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    reservation: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    majorRestriction: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
    },
}, {
    freezeTableName: true // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
});

Course = pool.define("course", {
    code: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    number: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    isEnglish: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    },
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    prerequisites: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
    },
    classRestriction: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
    },
}, {

    instanceMethods: {
        textualRepresentation: function() { return this.code + " " + this.number + (this.isEnglish ? "E" : "") }
    },
    freezeTableName: true // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
});

Schedule = pool.define("schedule", {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    validUntil: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE()
    },
}, {
    freezeTableName:true
});

Section.hasMany(Lesson);
Lesson.belongsTo(Section);
Course.hasMany(Section);
Section.belongsTo(Course);
Schedule.hasMany(Course);
Course.belongsTo(Schedule);

pool.sync();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second time the `sync` methods are called, they will not alter the tables because the tables have already been created in the database from the first `sync` calls.  If `sync` is called with the options `{ force: true }` it will drop the table and recreate it.

Also, all the association definitions are not asynchronous, therefore this code could be shortened to this:

```
Section.hasMany(Lesson);
Lesson.belongsTo(Section);
Course.hasMany(Section);
Section.belongsTo(Course);
Schedule.hasMany(Course);
Course.belongsTo(Schedule);

sequelize.sync();
```

Comment: Great for hearing this. I did this, now there is no `CourseId` column in `Section` table. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are the tables from your previous work still in the db?

Comment: Can you post your model definitions?  I made some basic model defs to test this and am seeing `CourseId` in the `Sections` table.

Comment: Edited post, you can check now.

Comment: By the way I do have `belongsTo` relationships now, but not others. Should there be another column in models with `hasMany`? Is it a normal behaviour?

Comment: Still seeing `courseId` in `section`.  There is no need for another column in tables with hasMany.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93726/discussion-between-leviathlon-and-djstroky).